# Mobile SDK Error after upgrade to 8.x

Tags: mobile, sdk

Bill Mote: question on SF support Case #43394050

We are getting an occasional error after upgrading to 8.x in the Prod (Testflight) unit.

Fatal Exception: com.salesforce.security.keychainException
setObject:forKey:: Error saving value to the keychain: errSecInteractionNotAllowed.

Comment: We are seeing the same issue, crashes in our latest release using v8.0.7 have tremendously spiked. Any updates here?